# SQL: Determining from which table query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three tables:

### Table b

id_b (primary key)

name

### Table c

id_c (primary key)

id_b (links to table b)

name

### Table e

id_e (primary key)

id_b (links to table b)

id_c (links to table c)

company

If id_b exists in table c, id_b will not appear in table e.
In table e, only one value (id_b or id_c) will be not null.

For a given value of "id_b" I need to retrieve "name" from table c where id_b=given id_b. In the same way, I need to retrieve "company" from table e where id_b=given id_b. How can I determine the table from which I need to query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute both queries, only one of them will have a non-empty resultset. As one of the resultsets will always be empty (therefore no unrequired data will be transferred), there will be no theoretical drawback in performance compared to a solution where you previously check which table should be queried.

Comment: A Union was my first thought.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson The type of the `name` and `company` fields are not given in the question, but if they are the same (or at least convertible), union can also be a solution. It will also have circa the same performance.

Comment: A Union is not possible because I need to retrieve different number of fields on each case (in the question I show a resumed version).

Comment: Use static values for the extra fields.